# Installing PDCurses for Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, pdcurses

I've been searching for a solution to do this for a while now, but still unsure.  How do u install the PDCurses library in cygwin.  I have the zip, I just don't know where to place the files. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: If ncurses itself would be better how would I go about installing that with cygwin. Whichever one works. Basically how would I get ncurses like functionality in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I hate doing this but I solved it and wanted to get the answer out there.  Download the files http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/ at this location.  A more direct link is http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/3.4/.  I downloaded this one "pdc34dllw.zip". Place all files in the same location as the file you are compiling.

you must link the lib to your file like this

gcc ./your_file_name ./pdcurses.lib

and your done.  I think the *.dll needs to stay with the file though so include that when you distribute.

Make sure you include the file curses.h in your file.  #include "curses.h"

It seems to work with all the classic ncurses commands :-)